# Execute three executables one by one

Tags: linux, executable

Make three executables of three separate c files and  execute each of
these files one by one.If i write Makefile or is there any other approach.

Also if the above completes then i need to execute these files by writing it in flash
such that the one leads to execution of second and second leads to third.

Regards,
Mayank

Comment: you need to provide some examples of what you have already tried.  Also, is what you're looking for a BASH script?

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can use && operator for running programs for successive exit

ls && cd / && mv test1 test2

But if you just want to run without looking exit status use ;

ls ; cd / ; mv test1 test2